# What version of ECMAScript does CEF support?

Tags: javascript, chromium, chromium-embedded

Can you please help me determine the supported version of ECMAScript in the chromium embedded framework(cef)?

I want to use ECMAScript 6 with it.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the corresponding Chromium version: https://cefbuilds.com/

ECMAScript 6 is not yet completely supported on the latest stable version of CEF (Chromium 45) https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#chrome45

I would suggest for you to just use pre-processors like Babel.

Comment: Thank you.
We are currently using babel, I was looking to find out if we could stop, but it appears not. At least not yet.